# jquery hover menu of part of the circle - how to?

Tags: jquery, effects

i have an interesting question and i dont know the solution...

If you check this index image: [image: http://naprej.net/index.jpg]
<sub>(source: [naprej.net](http://naprej.net/index.jpg))</sub>

How could i make that each section of menu would have roll over effect - such as jquery fade in and out.

The problem is that it is in circle shape.. how do you define the object which is in the shape like at that picture?

Comment: You should go for SVG as raphael.js for this kind of behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Try this jquery plugin for image map:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight